# Twitter Bootstrap hover display

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hover

I have a row of images that I want a hover box to cover the images. However, for some reason, my code functions to only covers some of the images completely. Others have a missing stripe on the right hand side. I can't figure out why that is. Any ideas?

HTML Code: http://codepad.org/hMqDsXS0

CSS Code: http://codepad.org/KJYr4aJP

Comment: You're gonna need to create a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) with only relevant code to your question, those pages you've linked are too big to see the wood from the trees.

Comment: You're gonna have to be alot more clear.....very hard to undesrtand what you're talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fiddle of your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/ttGgH/4/

I changed the span class,

```
.main-feature-title {
        width: 100%;
}
```

and I added this as well:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This feature will help elements size correctly to the box, especially when they have borders applied.